# How to use JPA and JDBC transactions within the same Spring transaction scope?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jdbc, transactions

We are migrating an existing application to new platform with very minimal rewriting of the code. The legacy app uses EJB's and JDBC for the database operations. We have now replaced EJB with Spring framework. As part of this migration, we ran into a major issue with transaction management. Within a single transaction, we have many db operations with Spring JPA as well as JDBC. When there is an exception thrown, all the data that's updated through Spring JPA is getting rolled back where as the data that's updated through JDBC is still getting committed to the database. We have this scenario in thousands of places. The code looks something like below.

```
public void save() throws Exception {
    DbUtil util = new DbUtil(); // DB utility for JDBC operations

    repo1.save(bean1);
    
    // Some code here
    
    util.insert("insert into ...");
    
    // Some more code here
    
    repo2.save(bean2); // Exception thrown here
}
```

We have tried with @Transactional annotation and it seems to be working. However, identifying the transaction entry point in thousands of places is a major task and that's consuming up a lot of time. We are looking for a common solution (Ex: some changes in DbUtil) so that we don't have to spend weeks / months of effort on this.

Is there a cleaner way to manage transaction that either completely commits or rollsback everything?

PS: Below is a sample method from DbUtil that inserts a record to the db.

```
public int insert(String query, List values) throws SQLException {
    int count = 0;
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;

    try {
        conn = DbConnectionFactory.getDbConnection();
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);

        if (values != null) {
            // Loop thru the values and set to prepared statement
        }
        
        count = stmt.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.write(query, e);
        throw (e);
    } finally {
        // Put the connection back to the pool
        DbConnectionFactory.returnResources(conn, null, stmt);
    }
    
    return count;
}
```

Comment: You don't have a layer that all actions go through, what one could consider a service layer?

Comment: Could you add the code for your `DbUtil` class? That would shed some light on this.

Comment: @JensSchauder, this is a legacy app that was developed a long ago. Unfortunately, we don't have a service layer. The UI is built through JSP's and JSF. So, many of the entry points on server side are JSF beans.

Comment: You could write an aspect  / pointcut that will start a transaction for each JSF maanged bean/component. Nonetheless if the `DbUtil` does its own connection management / commit this wouldn't (fully) work without integrating it with Spring (hence te request for the code in question).

Comment: @M.Deinum, I have modified my question to include a method from DbUtil. Please check.

Comment: And what does the `DbConnectionFactory` class do? Ideally the modified one uses the `ApplicationContext` to obtain the `DataSource` and uses `DataSourceUtils.getConnection` to obtain a `Connection`. As that will re-use the one from JPA (or bind one so that JPA can reuse it) and thus can operate in the same transaction.

Comment: As you mentioned, DbConnectionFactory uses DataSourceUtils to retrieve and return the connection.